# Checking Mutex release

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, file, mutex

I have a multithreaded application written in C++. And I'm using mutex for file writes. I have a suspicion that somewhere during the execution of the program, the mutex isn't being released.
So I was wondering if there was a way to check for mutex locks and releases on a file, programmatically or otherwise.
I'm running the code on SuseLinux, btw.
Thanks,

Comment: The problem was actually something else, seemingly silly. I hadn't initialized a bool variable in some of the constructors assuming it would be initialized to false by default.
Now if you're wondering how could I be confused whether the problem was due to a mutex or wrong-initialization; well, if you looked at the code, I guess you will understand.
Anyways, thanks for the answers. They were helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging multi-threaded code. There is no magic bullet to solve your problems, but at the very least you should be using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) idioms to manage your mutex. This means wrapping the mutex in a C++ class that claims the mutex when instances of the class are created and releases it when it (the class instance) is destroyed. You can also profitably log the claim/releases, but be aware that this may introduce timing bugs and artefacts.

Comment: Boost::Threads library has a very nice set of portable RAII mutex... helps a lot with avoiding deadlock from lingering lock.